# In Elixir can function names be refactored safely without type spec?

Tags: refactoring, elixir, dynamic-typing

As the title asked. For example I want to rename a random function name in Elixir, can I do it safely?

Comment: That's sort of a broad question, don't you think?  If you're specifically asking about the rename function refactoring, then maybe that's how you should state your question.  As it stands right now it looks like you're looking for a generic answer of some sort.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find any places where the function is being called and change them to match.

One tool for helping with this is unit testing. ExUnit is available in Elixir, and Eunit is available in Erlang. For integration tests, the [Common Test](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/basics_chapter.html) framework is available in both languages, though I'm unaware of Elixir wrappers.

Another option is to use dialyzer, which you can integrate into an Elixir project easily with [Dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir). It's especially helpful if you include [type annotations](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html) in your code. Even if you don't use them, dialyzer can find many function contract violations in your code, though you still have to fix them manually.

Dialyxir is just an elixir integration for [dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html), which is an Erlang tool. [Function specifications](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) are applicable in Erlang as well

Comment: You forgot mention [RefactorErl](http://plc.inf.elte.hu/erlang/index.html).

Comment: Can't forget something you're unaware of. :) I'll have to go look it up!